# How should I format header of a book according to my specifications?

Tags: header-footer

I want to format header of my book manually with chapter name & no. on odd pages and section name & no. on even pages as depicted below [image: even page with section name and number][image: odd page with chapter name and number]

Comment: What's the `3.` on the left side of the bottom image supposed to be?

Comment: Of course page numbers. Sorry for such a silly question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My impression is that you're confusing odd and even pages: in most format what you have for page 2 is used with odd pages (right hand side) and what's for page 3 is used with even pages (left hand side). Can you tell what document class you're using?

Comment: I tried \fancyheader but its not working out.

Comment: May be the page numbers is other way round.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

A  solution with `titlesec/titleps`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\newcommand*\hdrformat{\color{SlateGray4}\sffamily}
\sethead[\hdrformat\thesection~\sectiontitle\,$\mathbf]$][][\hdrformat\thepage.]{\hdrformat\thepage.}{}{\hdrformat$[$\,\chaptername~\thechapter}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[4-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]